# web service in tornado is non responsive - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, web-services, asynchronous, tornado

I have RESTFul web services running on tornado 4.4.3 server on Python 2.7.
The web service needs to execute some long running python scripts (6-7 hours).

The implementation is

1. The main thread on Tornado receives the request
2. calls a method annotated as coroutine
3. using subprocess and yield to invoke this long running python script

At the end of the execution, the tornado server goes into idle state.
It is able to acknowledge the incoming requests but is NOT invoking the other python script(Long running)

Thanks for taking time to look at this.

Please let me know for anymore information.

Comment: We'll need to see some code, preferably a complete example we can run that reproduces the problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I'd be able to share only the web service code and not the python script which it calls as it proprietary. Also, could you please tell me if having a supervisord and nginx set up will help avoid such scenarios?

Comment: also, this set up is running on windows 2008 server. could you please suggest me for any logs in tornado that might capture this issue, please. currently i only application logs and not enabled any logs from tornado server itself.